# what is the problem if program is crash, when click save button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a simple todo list embedded in my main app,
I had established it in a separate project, then I add it to my main project carefully, everything is good but, when I write the todo and click save button the program is crash! what is the problem?

my code:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave
                                               target:self
                                               action:@selector(save_Clicked:)]
 autorelease];
```

then the save_Clicked implementation is :

```
- (void) save_Clicked:(id)sender {
    HomeAppDelegate *appDelegate =
    (HomeAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //Create a todo Object.
    todo *todoObj = [[todo alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:0];
    todoObj.todotitle = txttodotitle.text;
    todoObj.tododes = txttododes.text;
    /*
     NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:txttododes.text];
     todoObj.tododes = temp;
     [temp release];
     */
    todoObj.isDirty = NO;
    todoObj.isDetailViewHydrated = YES;

    //Add the object
    [appDelegate addtodo:todoObj];

    //Dismiss the controller.
    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and the error massages output in console is:

> 2010-06-03 17:12:45.720 Home[29728:207] No Errors
>   2010-06-03 17:12:45.726 Home[29728:207] WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: in .  Please remove your implementation of this method and set the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType to move to the new cell layout behavior.  This method will no longer be called in a future release.
>   2010-06-03 17:12:59.447 Home[29728:207] *** Assertion failure in -[todo addtodo], /Users/HOME/Desktop/withretriveAnn/Home copy 5-ToDO/Classes/todo.m:90
>   2010-06-03 17:12:59.448 Home[29728:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while creating add statement. 'no such table: todo''

- for sure I used iPhone Database to save the ToDo list.

Comment: Might help to post the code...

Comment: Supply your code, or at the very least, the error messages output in the Xcode console when your app crashes.

Comment: …it can be anywhere.  Without seeing code, this question is impossible to answer. Without seeing the crash message this problem is impossible to answer. Please update your question

Comment: ok sorry, I update my question with code and error messages, help me please with thanks.

Comment: It appears that you're using Core Data and didn't create a 'todo' entity. In your XCode project, under Resources, double click on the xcdatamodel file and either add a 'todo' entity or check to see if it is misspelled or capitalized differently.

Comment: I doesn't have something with xcdatamodel name in resources! :(
just "mytodo.sqlit" that what I copied from old project, 
I know that I have something wrong but I don't know what is it?!

Answer (score 0):

Check typos in your table names.  Entities (and thus tables) start with a capital letter and your error has a lower case.  I suspect this is a simple typo of Todo.